# My override of Async signature of GetWebResponse throws a runtime exception when setting property on response

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, asynchronous

This is related to a question I asked a couple weeks ago but never got an answer on.  I need to override the asynchronous signature of System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse, to set the ContentType to utf-8.
(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c2xze5ez(v=vs.110).aspx)

I'm able to do this just fine with the synchronous call, but the asynchronous implementation throws a runtime exception if I try to set that same property - though I can SEE the property if I examine the response in the debugger.

I'm hoping it's something dumb that I've overlooked.

In the example below, I've created a Web Reference (yes, the old kind - no, I can't change it to a service reference right now) to the TempConvert service found here, and called it OldSchoolReference.TempConvert:
http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx

Then I inherited from that reference, as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1.OldSchoolReference
{
    public partial class ServiceProxy : TempConvert
    {
        protected override System.Net.WebResponse GetWebResponse(System.Net.WebRequest request)
        {
            WebResponse response = base.GetWebResponse(request);
            response.Headers.Set("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=UTF-8");    // Works fine!
            return response;
        }

        protected override System.Net.WebResponse GetWebResponse(System.Net.WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result)
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = base.GetWebResponse(request, result) as HttpWebResponse;
            response.Headers.Set("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=UTF-8"); 
            // You will note that this implementation is an System.Net.HttpWebResponse whereas the sychronous one above is a System.Net.WebResponse
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm exercising the behavior with a simple one-button windows form that calls the service.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OldSchoolReference.ServiceProxy service = new OldSchoolReference.ServiceProxy();

        service.CelsiusToFahrenheitCompleted += CallBack;
        service.CelsiusToFahrenheitAsync("0"); // returns 32, naturally
    }

    private static void CallBack(object sender, OldSchoolReference.CelsiusToFahrenheitCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Result);
    }
```

But it's throwing an exception :(

[image: Exception]

As you can see in the screenshot, there's a ContentType property on the response, but it seems the setter method for the property isn't implemented.  Yes, I know it's already set to utf-8, but that's not the issue.  I need to force it to always be utf-8 via my override.

[image: Debugger view]

Lastly, but of no consequence for me, the synchronous implementation I've included the override for as well does work - but I need it to be on the async version.

Does anyone know how I can set this property on the asynchronous response?  I would be much obliged!

Comment: I'm now trying to set it via the headers.  It seems to work fine on my example here at home, I'll need to check at work on Monday to see if that resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If it being an HttpWebResponse have you tried just doing `var response = base.GetWebResponse(request, result) as WebResponse`or even just `var response = base.GetWebResponse(request, result)`

Comment: It throws the same exception, sadly.

Comment: What about creating a new response from scratch that you can control as you wish